# POSIX condition variable & mutex "competition"

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix, mutex, condition-variable

When a thread waits on a condition variable, the associated mutex is (atomically) released (unlocked). When that condition variable is signaled (by a different thread), one (for signal) or all (for broadcast) waiting thread(s) is/are awakened, automatically re-acquiring (locking) the mutex.

What will happen if one or more other threads are waiting to acquire (lock) that same mutex, but not waiting on the same condition? Are the thread(s) waiting on the condition variable guaranteed to be awakened (and thus acquire the mutex) before the mutex can be acquired (locked) by the other threads, or could the other thread(s) acquire (lock) the mutex before the thread(s) waiting on the condition variable?

[Note: the example below is simplified for clarity. Thread_B does not really start Thread_C, but Thread_C is guaranteed to not be running until after Thread_B has acquired the mutex - it does not compete with Thread_B for the mutex after Thread_A waits on the condition variable]

Thread_A:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
while (!someState) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&myCondVar,&myMutex);
}
// do something
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
```

Thread_B:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
// do other things
someState = true;
// start Thread_C here
pthread_cond_signal(&myCondVar);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
```

Thread_C:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
// can I reach this point after Thread_B releases the mutex,
// but before Thread_A re-acquires it after being signaled?

// do things that may interfere with Thread_A...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
```

Edit: The accepted answer below was chosen because it makes clear that whether or not a reader agrees with the interpretation given, there is enough ambiguity that the only safe assumption to make is that of the respondent. Note that others well-versed in C++-standard-speak may find the text totally unambiguous... I am not in that group.

Comment: `What will happen if one or more other threads are waiting to acquire (lock) that same mutex, but not waiting on the same condition?` - it's the same as two threads waiting for the same mutex. Note that from docs `The effect of using more than one mutex for concurrent ... pthread_cond_wait() operations on the same condition variable is undefined;`

Comment: @Kamil Cuk note that I am using the same mutex for pthread_cond_wait() as I am to protect pthread_cond_signal(). Only one mutex and one condVar in play.

Comment: Why do you have to use the same mutex for two purposes? Do you have to pay for each mutex objects? Logically mutex and it's condition variable are married to each other, and there is no reason to use one without the other.

Comment: @SergeyA I agree. Using one mutex is simpler (and possibly reduces chance of deadlock... but that's also an issue of poor design/implementation). If I cannot confirm that signaled threads are not competing for the mutex with other (non-signaled) threads, I will use a different, unique mutex as you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about acquiring a mutex when awakened from `pthread_cond_[timed]wait()` compared to any other thread already blocked in `pthread_mutex_lock()` trying to acquire the same mutex.

[Per the POSIX 7 `pthread_cond_signal()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) (bolding mine):

> If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy shall determine the order in which threads are unblocked. When each thread unblocked as a result of a `pthread_cond_broadcast()` or `pthread_cond_signal()` returns from its call to `pthread_cond_wait()` or `pthread_cond_timedwait()`, the thread shall own the mutex with which it called `pthread_cond_wait()` or `pthread_cond_timedwait()`. The thread(s) that are unblocked shall contend for the mutex according to the scheduling policy (if applicable), and **as if each had called `pthread_mutex_lock()`**.

Acquiring the mutex after waking up from `pthread_cond_[timed]wait()` is **required** to be **exactly** as if the thread had called `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

In short, any of the threads can acquire the mutex.

Comment: I don't read that section of the standard the way you do. I read it just to say that you (the programmer) can only expect the same guarantees from the implementation that you would have if each called `pthread_mutex_lock`. I don't read that as a requirement that the implementation provide exactly the same behavior outside the guarantees in the standard. No compliant application could tell the difference. (As a general rule of standards interpretation, if a standard is at all ambiguous, read it so as not to impose an onerous and useless requirement on an implementation.)

Comment: I may be overthinking this, but I did read this document. In each case, as I read it, it is specifically referring to threads that are unblocked from waiting on the condition variable. It very clearly indicates that if multiple threads are waiting on the same condition variable, the order in which they are awakened (re-acquire the mutex) is the same as normal (multiple threads waiting to acquire a mutex -- that is, up to the scheduler and apparently random). But I am not sure if it's saying that the mutex is unlocked, and any thread can possibly acquire it, before the signaled thread(s).

Comment: @ags I made it clear that awakened threads are treated the same as threads *already* blocked in `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The standard uses the word "shall contend for the mutex ... as if each had called `pthread_mutex_lock()`".  That seems to me to be a pretty clear requirement that the contention shall be the same.  I'll agree there's no discernible difference from an application's perspective.

Comment: @AndrewHenle When used in a standard, "as if" usually means with no differences observable to a portable application that makes no assumptions not guaranteed by the standard. Here, your interpretation places a particularly onerous requirement on the implementation that cannot even be detected by an application that doesn't make non-portable assumptions. (This may seem like nitpicking, but a surprisingly large fraction of serious bugs not caught until after release come from thinking standards make guarantees they don't make and then relying on guarantees you don't have.)

Comment: I read "...as if..." to mean that it it would be perfectly valid for `pthread_cond_wait(c, m)` to _actually call_ `pthread_mutex_lock(m)` just before it returns, and it means that there is no requirement for the posix thread library or the operating system to treat that call any differently from any other call to pthread_mutex_lock(m) from any other thread or, from anywhere else in the code.